# Matching up to special character

Tags: regex

I need to capture something until a `,` (comma).

Example payload1: `AgentBrand: Internet Explorer,`
Example Payload2: `AgentBrand: OutlookPlug-in,`

From the above payload I need to capture whatever coming after `AgentBrand:`
until the command (`,`).

I have Tried AgentBrand:\s+(\w+\s+\w+) .But this will be become a lengthy regex.

Thanks

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: negated character class allows to match any character except specified thus `AgentBrand:[^,]*`

Comment: You seem to be new to using regex, i would suggest you take a look at https://regex101.com its a helpful site to help understand and validate your regex's. If you have a problem with a regex statement you have built please add it to the question and we can help point out any misunderstandings that you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current regex that you are using - `AgentBrand:\s+(\w+\s+\w+)` will only catch cases where you have at least two words separated by a space and even in those cases it will only pick up the first two words (when there may be more).

A better regex to use would be - `AgentBrand:\s*(.*?),`

what this does is

`AgentBrand:` - looks for the string 'AgentBrand:'

`\s*` - matches zero or more space characters

`(.*?)` - captures any characters non-greedily [takes minimum matches to satisfy result]

`,` - looks for a comma at the end

Also as a note, the length of a regex is not always a good reason to avoid using one. The regex in your example is not that long and is quite simple and could be freely if it met all your requirements. Looking at the complexity of a regex is a better choice

Comment: I tried another one and worked : AgentBrand\:\s+([^,]*)

Comment: Your comment is also correct.

Comment: @Tobin yes that would also work as it matches any non-comma character an infinite amount of times

Comment: @Tobin, your's is probably the best.

You could also use ^\w+:\s([^,]*), & it will return the same group if all of them are 'AgentBrand'. Also applicable if the line starts with any other word in place of 'AgentBrand' and you wish to capture them all.

Comment: also: AgentBrand:\s+(.+?),

Comment: @ParvBanks you may need `?` after the `+` otherwise its greedy and can select more than you need

Comment: Ah, yes! thanks for pointing that out :)

I thought we could make it shorter with this one.


Looking at it now, your's is better :P